# Java StringBuilder Class, Why Extra 16 Empty Elements?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I was looking Java Class String Builder and was wondering why is it adding 
extra 16 empty elements trailing the string for following constructors

1. StringBuilder(CharSequence cs): Constructs a string builder containing the same characters as the specified CharSequence, **plus an extra 16 empty elements trailing theCharSequence.**
2. String Builder(String s): Creates a string builder whose value is initialized by the specified string, **plus an extra 16 empty elements trailing the string.**

Why is the extra 16 empty elements are needed when StringBuilder can change its capacity whenever is
needed?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Maybe to avoid buffer reallocation at the first `append()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16 characters is the default free space allocated in any `StringBuilder` constructor except for the one in which you supply the capacity yourself (beside the constructors you already mentioned, the constructor with no parameters also allocates 16 characters of initial capacity).

It allows you to append some characters to the StringBuilder without imediatelly having to increase the capacity. The reason for this behavior is most likely performance.

Comment: Hi Eran, thanks for clearing things for this question. Now I kind of get why 16 elements are added. But one thing is would that effectively increase the performance, overall? It's only 16 characters though..

Comment: @denden130 Even if you end up adding more than 16 characters to the `StringBuilder`, this initial capacity would save you one call to `expandCapacity`, which creates a new char array and copies the current char array to it. If you create many StringBuilders in your application, it can add up.

Comment: I appreciate your further explanation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder`s have a `capacity`, which is the amount of storage available for character insertion.  If you try to add more, new storage space needs to be allocated to accomodate those.  New `StringBuilder`s build with those constructors add 16 to the capacity to allow you to add more characters without having to re-allocate.  It's a performance thing.

Note you can always create a `StringBuilder` with a specified capacity using the `StringBuilder(int capacity)` constructor, if you know how many characters it will hold.

Comment: Thanks Tonio for the answer. I really appreciate your explanation but I had to select the one that came in first :( anyways thanks a lot!